# Binary search in php over list of strings

Tags: php

I have a file containing about 30K songs names. I have to use this list for automatic text  suggestion with AJAX.
Some of the names also start with numbers. My question is can I do binary search over this list ?  If yes, how ?

Comment: Define "binary search", please.
How do you want the results to look like? Is is a dropdown?

Comment: Use a database... don't try doing this with that big of a file.

Comment: @silkfire Yes, its will show as in drop down like in Google

Comment: @Orangepill text search from database are much slower

Comment: How do you figure...I would like to see benchmarks showing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all sort the list;

Suppose, the first letter the user has typed is "A";

Start with high = 0 and low = number of strings -1;

Then you can define a **high** and a **low** index where high is the last index that starts with "A" and low is the first index that has a string starts with "A". With two binary searches this can be achieved.

So if the next letter typed is say "B" then you make another binary search in the range high and low defined above and adjust the high and low again with two binary searches. Make sure you search for the second character of the strings between high and low to be matched with "B" and so on :)

Note: I'd suggest to use Database to do so, but as you queried if there's any way to use binary search, I'm answering this way :)

Simple sql query: `SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE 'prefix%'` to select strings those start with 'prefix' stored in the column 'column_name' of 'table_name' table

Comment: Big fall down here is you have to populate and search an array of 30,000 elements with each request.

Comment: @Orangepill: the list is pre populated I believe. and the search is binary search so lg(30,000)<=16 (where, lg = log2) So there'll be at most 16+16=32 comparisons at each step.

Comment: Won't I have to query database every time a user will press a key, if I will use database ?

Comment: @Fallen in mysql keys are represented by default as a binary tree. Do your big O notation there and take out the performance impact of having to read in the array and sort it

Comment: @Orangepill: Please note that I've added a note to my answer. I also suggest to use database(I've created similar functionality using Database) but my answer is only to show that it's possible with binary search. even if he had asked it in algorithm section I'd add how to solve this using trie :)

Comment: @Orangepill Can you provide me with database table query that I will have to create to use mysql keys. I am new to SQL.

Comment: So, I should create a table with these strings as primary keys ?

Comment: @silverflash: not necessarily as primary keys but that'd be better choice indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mixed array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = false ] )`

[php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)